# Eloquent number of times one many to many relationship occurs

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I am struggling with eloquent to do something quite specific.

I have two tables, 'meals' and 'products', and a pivot table meal_product which associates each product with one meal.

One important thing is that a product has an energy, in kcal.

Given that a user can have different meals that can contain one same product, I'd like to get the total energy of the 5 products that the user consumes the most.

I also had to select the 5 products with the highest energetic value consumed by one particular user, and this is what I did:

```
$highProducts = Product::whereHas('meals', function($q) use($user_id) {
            $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
        })->whereNotNull('energetic_value')
        ->orderBy('energetic_value', 'DESC')
        ->take(5)
        ->get();
```

This works but I can't figure out how to adapt it so that it counts the number of times a user has consumed a product and then multiplying it with its energetic value to get the total.

Comment: why not just use COUNT() ?

Comment: $highProducts->count();

Comment: This just gives me a number of products, which I already limited to 5 by stating take(5). What I need is this multliplication:
nb of times a user consumed a product * energetic value of this same product
And then select the 5 highest values

Comment: Have you looked at `withCount()`? https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models